# Handling SelectedItemChanged TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I'm trying to get the current selection of a `TreeView`. I want to handle this in my `MainWindow.xaml.cs` but the `TreeView` is actually in another widow called `Window1` in the same namespace. How can I do this? Here's what I have so far:

**WPF Code**

```
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LogHunter"
        xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:dxt="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid" x:Class="LogHunter.Window1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core"
        dx:ThemeManager.Theme="DXStyle"
        Title="Window1" Height="750" Width="750">
    <Grid>
<TreeView x:Name="treeView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Height="Auto" SelectedItemChanged="clientChanged"/>


    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**C# Handler**

```
public void clientChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.OriginalSource);
        }
```

**Error I'm getting**

> 'Window1'
>   does not contain a definition for 'clientChanged' and no extension
>   method 'clientChanged' accepting a first argument of type 'Window1'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Answer (score 0):

You need a way to share the SelectedItem between the two Window:

1) You can use MVVM and share your viewmodel between your Windows.

2) You you need something fast: I suppose you are creating an instance of Window1 from your MainWindow, you can do something like this in your MainWindow:

```
  Window1 w1 = new Window1();

  w1.treeView.SelectedItemChanged += new RoutedPropertyChangedEventHandler<object>(treeView_SelectedItemChanged);

  w1.Show();
```

Remember to detach this event when you'll destroy Window1.